# Laravel Validate ForeginKey

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a table that is fk from another table. when I try to delete the record, I get an error because it is not possible to delete a record that is used as fk in another table. Has anyone ever used laravel's validator to validate this situation?

Comment: If you validate for this you will get a validation error, now you're getting a database error. It's much easier to catch the database error and convert it to whatever error you need it to be instead. Validation is usually for input not integrity constraints.

Comment: It returns a QueryException, It is a rule not to delete record, where it is used as fk in another record.

Comment: Can't you just do `try { /* query */ } catch (QueryException $e) { abort(422,"Some informative user message that they've messed up"); }`